# Javascript to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Convert Form data to JavaScript. but I only wants few submitted fields to be converted to JSON. For fields which do not have an input in my form, I don't want them to in my JSON. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to get help.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. Please provide a [mcve] along with your code attempt to solve this yourself along with a more specific code related problem statement

Comment: Loop over the inputs in the form. If the input has a value, add it to the object.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to delete the unwanted properties from object, before converting to JSON

delete obj.UnwantedPropertyName

Comment: Need an object before you can do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery just construct the json object manually.

```
var a = {
    'field1': $('#field1_id').val(),
    'field2': $('#field2_id').val(),
    'field3': $('#field3_id').val()
};
```

Comment: question isn't tagged jQuery